# Java swing layout problems

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, border-layout

I am struggling with layouts in my application.  I am totally new to java.  I developed an application I had developed sometime ago in VB.  In trying to learn java I developed the same application with absolute layouts (learned from youtube tutorial) and tabbed panes.  I didn't like what I developed, so I started over.  This time using layout managers and card layout as main layout.  I am struggling to get things the way I want.  I spent many days of trial and error getting my panels the way I want.  I have a main class with 4 different cards.  I tried using eclipse and window builder to try and design my panels, but that was an epic failure.  I've gone back to designing my layouts without the design in eclipse and basically settled on border layout as my basis for all cards.  Right now, I am having trouble with one panel.  The first panel is my original attempt at what I want with absolute layout. The second pic is my latest attempt using border layout with one button (Back) in SOUTH, some text fields in CENTER, and my main display in NORTH.  The NORTH display is not nearly wide enough.  Here is the code code for my NORTH panel:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panelNorth = new JPanel();
        add(panelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        panelNorth.add(scrollPane);

        tableDisplayScores = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(tableDisplayScores);

        JPanel panelCenter = new JPanel();
        add(panelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Before I go completely insane, how can I increase the width of my NORTH panel without going absolute?  Or am I going at this completely wrong?

Absolute layout example:

[image]

Layout manager example:
[image: description here]

Comment: Please edit your post and tell us more about desired output and observed result and less about your struggles. Only information relevant towards understanding and solving your actual coding problem should be posted. Also please create and post a valid compilable and runnable [mcve].

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: Images showing desired and observed results would also help much. You may not be able to post them directly to your question, but if you post a link to images you've posted online (a link to the images, not to the web page that holds them), we can place them for you.

Comment: OK, I see that you do in fact have image links, and so I've added true images to your question.

Comment: [Matisse, the GUI builder for NetBeans,](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) is free and will quickly make almost any kind of layout you want.  You should get that instead of trying to do this on your own.

Comment: While what @markspace states will work, if you use a GUI builder without first understanding how the basic layouts work, you will only hurt yourself. First learn the layout managers, then use a GUI builder if you so decide.

Comment: To the OP: it looks like your main problem is you want the columns in your table to be wider, like the absolute layout example.  Is that correct?

Comment: If you post a valid [mcve] we could help you solve this problem in a jiffy, since it looks to be an easy problem to solve. The overall layout needs to be BorderLayout, and again we can show you if you post small compilable runnable program code.

Comment: @markspace I tried with eclipse and got nowhere.  Is NetBeans Matisse better?  I want the whole NORTH panel to be larger like in my absolute layout.

Comment: I've never used Eclipse.  Matisse is pretty easy imo.  Just follow the tutorial and you'll have a good idea how it works.  However you probably won't use a BorderLayout;  Matisse uses SpringLayout by default.  Just lay out a panel how you want it, then add that to a top level JFrame.  Adding space or setting the size of components is easy to do.

Comment: I figured it out.  Once again by trial and error.  I eliminated the panelNorth and added my scrollPane to BorderLayout.NORTH.    `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();  
  add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);  
  
  tableDisplayScores = new JTable();  
  scrollPane.setViewportView(tableDisplayScores);`

Comment: OTP.  How do I make my comment above readable?  I put the code in back tics, but appeared to make no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment states, I figured this out with trial and error.  I eliminated the panelNorth and added my scrollPane to BorderLayout.NORTH:

```
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        tableDisplayScores = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(tableDisplayScores);
```